# How to get value of div from inspect element using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to get the return value of the div modal popup dialog. 
However, I could not get the value by using the

```
selenium.GetAttribute("id=lblPopUpMessageType");
```

What I wish to achieve is when I able to get the value then I can catch whether which progress is done.

For example, the code is like below:

```
 <span id="lblPopUpMessageType">error</span>  (If i get the "error" value i know it is fail) 
or 
 <span id="lblPopUpMessageType">success</span> (This mean success)
```

Well, I am not able to get by using the above function. 
I also tried with Selenium.GetElementIndex().ToString() but not working. I am new to Selenium, any help would be appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `selenium.getText("xpath to ur span")` rather than using selenium.getAttribute.

As `getAttribute()` method gives the value of an attribute within any given tag.

Comment: thank you for reply... but it still return me nothing... 
i tried with string abc=selenium.GetText("xpath=lblPopUpMessageType");
i return abc in a textbox.. it give me null value

Comment: write it as selenium.getText(//span[@id='lblPopUpMessageType']).The way you are writing xpath is wrong.You can also refer tools like Firepath and Xpath checker for getting xpath.

If you are not comfortable with xpath you can also write it as selenium.getText("id=lblPopUpMessageType").But in that case the id must be unique in whole page.

Comment: hi Abhi, i tried with your selenium.getText(//span[@id='lblPopUpMessageType']) but it give me comment out of the rest of the sentence... any idea? I also tried with 2nd method but it still return nothing...in addition , the div that store this span id is invisible status, it will only give value when the modal dialog show up with error/success...

Comment: i am using visual basic 2010. Comment out mean the words after // all become green in color...

Comment: Ohh Got you..actualy You hav to pass it as string. selenium.getText("//span[@id='lblPopUpMessageType']");

Comment: i tried with  selenium.getText("//span[@id='lblPopUpMessageType']"); and selenium.getText("id=lblPopUpMessageType") but why they are giving me "" value still? @@

Comment: It may be that when you are getting the text from span there is "" associated with that and it is changed to 'error' or 'success' after some event or action.Wait for that event or action to be completed.

Comment: thank you ahbi ...but i wait until whole program finish... it return me nothing still..